# Unable to use decorators

Tags: python, function, arguments, decorator

this below mentioned decorators given error. How to use decorators here:

```
def mfx(fx):
    def mfx():
     print("The list has been sorted to:")
     fx()
    return mfx
```

While calling the decorators in for loop method

```
@mfx
def list_sort(list):

    new_list = []
    while my_list:
        min = my_list[0]  
        for x in my_list: 
            if x < min:
                min = x
        new_list.append(min)
        my_list.remove(min)    
    print(new_list)
```

This is how I call the method

```
my_list=[0,10,2,1,8]

list_sort(my_list)
```

Error message on `list_sort(my_list)`: `TypeError: mfx.<locals>.mfx() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: It might help to give the outer and inner `mfx` different names.

Comment: list_sort(my_list)
TypeError: mfx.<locals>.mfx() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Generally, it is a bad idea to shadow global names like `list`, `min`, and `mfx` (defined by you).

Answer (score 1):

You also need to pass through the arguments to the wrapped function.

```py
def mfx(fx):
    def wrapped(*args):
        print("The list has been sorted to:")
        fx(*args)
    return wrapped
```

Comment: And for more general functions `def mfx(*args, **kwargs)`.  And your two functions shouldn't have the same name as mentioned above.  That makes the code harder to read.

Comment: @FrankYellin Good point. I didn't notice the naming issue at first.